# How browser open 6 parallel connections on http1?

Tags: phantomjs

I want to know how browser open 6 parallel tcp connections when communicating on http1. So I've tried to analyze phantomjs. As analyzing source code, I wondered a few things.

1) what is the role of webserver.cpp?
2) where is the source code about multiple parallel tcp connections? is that in mongoose.c which is in "src/mongoose/"?

Thank you.

Comment: Which browser? What are you talking about? What does the question have to do with any of these tags?

Comment: @NeilLunn I want to know principle of implementation about multiple http connection on Web browser.